# C++ Stack generic class, int variable getting 32765 as value instead of 1

Tags: c++, qt, variables

The title says the most of it. My variable "full" gets the value 3276 instead of 0;

Here is my header;

```
#ifndef GENERICSTACK_H
#define GENERICSTACK_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class genericStack
{
    int MaxItems;
    T* stack;

    int empty;
    int full;
    int length;

public:

    genericStack(int);
    void push(T);
    T pop();
};

#endif // GENERICSTACK_H
```

Here is my .cpp file

Only the constructor is important really. Because Qt debugger shows that it does not change value in the constructor. It is originally 32765 before anything.

```
#include "genericstack.h"

template <class T> genericStack<T>::genericStack(int size)
{
  MaxItems = size;

  stack = new T[MaxItems];

  empty = 1;
  full = 0;
}

template <class T> void genericStack<T>::push(T item)
{
  if(full == 1)
{
    cout << "The stack is full.";
  }else
{
    stack[length] = item;
    length++;
    empty = 0;
}

if(length == MaxItems)
    full = 1;

}

template <class T> T genericStack<T>::pop()
{
  T temp;

  if(empty == 1)
    {
      cout<< "The stack is already empty.";
      return NULL;
  }else
    {
      temp = stack[length];
      stack[length] = NULL;
      length--;
      full = 0;
    }

    if(length == 1)
        empty = 1;

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question to fix the problem. It makes the answers meaningless.

Comment: Okay sorry. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor doesn't set length to zero. When you use it as an array index, you stomp on memory, corrupting data.

Comment: Thank you! I will choose this to be the right answer when the website lets me.

Comment: When I get put length into the constructor, full gets fixed but length is only set to 0 whatever value I give it to. Could you tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: In the pop() method in genericstack.cpp
Now the stack doesnt store the values. I guess I need a lot of debugging. Thanks for all the help! I may try to fix it myself.

Comment: Use `return temp;` or throw an exception.